# Constraint unique, и null, можно ли настроить ограничение с пропуском null полей

Tags: sql-server

Существует таблица в которой поля `var1 int` и `var2 int` должны быть уникальными в комбинации т.е. выглядеть примерно так:

```
select id, var1, var2 from #table
```

result:

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 1 1
```

но

```
ALTER TABLE #table   
ADD CONSTRAINT cons_uniq_vars UNIQUE (var1, var2);   
GO
```

не дает быть полям с `null` повторяющимися

```
insert into #table values
(0, null),
(0, null) /*здесь выдаст ошибку*/
```

текст ошибки:

> Нарушение "cons_uniq_vars" ограничения UNIQUE KEY. Не удается вставить повторяющийся ключ в объект "dbo.#table". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (0, NULL).

Я так понимаю что создается не ограничение а новый индекс, можно ли обойти это ограничение или такое решается только через триггер?

P.S.: 
[В этой статье ничего про это не сказано](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cons_uniq_vars ON #table(var1, var2) WHERE var2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, а на msdn есть статья где такая ситуация описывается или это вы на личном опыте открыли?

Comment: [Нашел](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  - ссылка на msdn